# how to return a string (varchar) in mysql UDF

Tags: mysql

How to return the argument? And how to return a single string? I have tried these but get an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 'a'' at line 2
```

I don't think "DETERMINISTIC" is the problem.
To return argument:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test_foo`;
CREATE FUNCTION test_foo (a VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS VARCHAR DETERMINISTIC
RETURN a
```

To return single string:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test_foo`;
CREATE FUNCTION test_foo ()
RETURNS VARCHAR DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 'a'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `VARCHAR` without its length.

As per documentation:

[***The CHAR and VARCHAR Types***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)

> The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates
>   the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example,
>   CHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters.

Hence, change your function definition as below and it should be working.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_foo;

CREATE FUNCTION test_foo ( a VARCHAR( 1 ) )
RETURNS VARCHAR( 1 ) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN a;
```